# Add CollectionView Items programmatically in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have already created a collectionView item for photo display. If I select photos from library and its successfully uploaded and then uploaded photos displayed perfectly.

Issue is : After the photo selection from library and during photo upload collectionview is empty no activity means little gap til final upload. I need to add collectionView item with in this time with activity indicator.

I am not getting an idea where I actually append item. I need to cover up this gap time with append collectionview items with activity indicator.

`withTLPHAssets contains values of selected Images`

`var imageAppData: ResponseData?`

my dataSource is `let dic = AppData?.imageList?[indexPath.row].url ?? " "`

Model:

```
struct ResponseData: Codable {
    var imageList : [ImageList]?
}

struct ImageList : Codable {

let url : String = ""
let projectUnitImageId : Int = 0
    
}
```

CollectionView:
I've added in `func dismissPhotoPicker`

```
for indexPath in self.collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems {
            if let cell = self.collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? PhotoCollectionViewCell {
                
                
            }
        }
```

Code:

```
func dismissPhotoPicker(withTLPHAssets: [TLPHAsset]) {
                // use selected order, fullresolution image
        for indexPath in self.collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems {
            if let cell = self.collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? PhotoCollectionViewCell {
                
                
            }
        }
            self.selectedAssets = withTLPHAssets
            for img in withTLPHAssets{
                let asset = img
                
                if asset.type == .photo {
                    let displayImage = asset.fullResolutionImage!
                    
                    let unitId = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "unitID")
                    let strUnit = String(describing: unitId)
                    let finalURL = Common.DEFAULT_HOST.url + "data/AddImages"
                    
                    guard let token = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "newToken") else {
                       print("invalid token")
                       return
                    }
                    
                    let image = displayImage
                    let imgData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.2)!

                    let parameters = ["ProjId": strUnit] //Optional for extra parameter

                    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
                            multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: "ImageList",fileName: "file.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
                            for (key, value) in parameters {
                                multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
                                } //Optional for extra parameters
                        },
                                     to: finalURL, headers: [ "Accept":"application/json", "Authorization":"Bearer \(token)"])
                    { (result) in
                        switch result {
                        case .success(let upload, _, _):

                            upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                                print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
                            })
                            
                            upload.responseJSON { response in
                                print(response.result.value)
                                self.pullData()
                            }

                        case .failure(let encodingError):
                            print(encodingError)
                        }
                    }
                    
                    
                    
                }
            }
```

cellForItemAt:

```
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellName, for: indexPath) as! PhotoCollectionViewCell
                        
            if(indexPath.row < (AppData?.imageList?.count ?? 0)){
                cell.imageView.isHidden = false
                cell.closeIcon.isHidden = false
                cell.addIcon.isHidden = true
                let dic = AppData?.imageList?[indexPath.row].url ?? " "
                //cell.imageView.image =  UIImage(url: URL(string: dic))
                let url = URL(string: dic)
                cell.imageView.kf.indicatorType = .activity
                cell.imageView.kf.setImage(
                    with: url,
                    placeholder: UIImage(named: "placeholder"),
                    options: [
                        .scaleFactor(UIScreen.main.scale),
                        .transition(.fade(1)),
                        .cacheOriginalImage
                    ])
                {
                    result in
                    switch result {
                    case .success(let value):
                        print("Task done for: \(value.source.url?.absoluteString ?? "")")
                        
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print("Job failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        
                    }
                }
                   
                
                let imgId = AppData?.imageList?[indexPath.row].projectUnitImageId
                
                cell.closeIcon.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                cell.closeIcon.tag = imgId ?? 0
                deleteAlertView.delegate = self
                let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(removeImage(_:)))
                cell.closeIcon.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
                
            } else {
                cell.imageView.isHidden = true
                cell.closeIcon.isHidden = true
                cell.addIcon.isHidden = true
            }
            
            return cell
        }
```

Comment: Can we see your `cellForItemAt indexPath` function? That will help understand the logic of how you populate the cells and what kind of data source you are using for the collection view.

Comment: @SanzioAngeli I have updated  `cellForItemAt` code

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a lot of the logic there already... Everything should be more or less controlled from the data source. I don't know what a lot of the functions in your `cellForItemAt indexPath` function do, but a guess would be to implement logic something like:

1. Modify your `imageList?[Int].url` to have optional url, so `imageList?[].url?`
2. Modify your `cellForItemAt indexPath` to keep the `imageView` hidden unless there is a valid url (ie, not `nil`)
3. Once an asset has been gathered from the picker, create and append a new image in your `imageList` but with a `nil` url. Reload the collection view with `reloadData()`. At this point your `numberOfItemsInSection` function should be returning the proper number of items, and the last cell will have the activity indicator showing because the image view is hidden.
4. Once the photo is uploaded and you have the url/asset. Update the corresponding data in the `imageList` and call `reloadData()` again.

You could also manually update the contents of the last cell once the data comes in. So you don't have to call `reloadData()` a second time

Another option is to simply append to `imageList` and manually create the data once they pick an image, and then do nothing once uploading has completed. This would look instantaneous and the upload would happen in the background.

Comment: Thank you let me try to implement and get back to you.